# I can't find a way to get input to be used in the equation and then display the results in html

Tags: javascript, html, calculator

My problem is that I can't find a way to get input in the HTML textbox and then use it in the equation I have.

I have a basic investment calculator to see how much you would profit after a set amount of time, given the return on your investment per month and the initial investment. The program returns your balance each month given that you have re-invested all of your profits from last month.

My program works when I replace the values of the variables with the `window.prompt()` function but that seems inconvenient so I want to make use of the textboxes as input methods for the equation variables.

this is my code so far:

```html
<form style="padding: 30px">
  <input type="number" id="holdingtime" placeholder=" hold on time" />
  <input type="number" id="initialinvestment" placeholder="initial investment" />
  <input type="number" id="monthlyreturn" placeholder="monthly return" />
  <input type="button">
  <br/>
</form>


<div class="dprogramitself" style="padding: 35px; padding-top: 1, font-size: 20px">

  <script>
    let holdtime = 201;
    let initialinvestment = 50000;
    let monthlyreturn = 0.15;

    document.eval("<li>", initialinvestment, "<br><hr>");
    for (let i = 0; i < holdtime; i++) {
      initialinvestment = initialinvestment + initialinvestment * monthlyreturn;
      document.write("<li>", initialinvestment, "<br><hr>");
    }
  </script>

</div>
```

sorry about the cheesy names I just try to be descriptive. Feel free to ask questions as I'm stuck and any help would be appreciated. I'm sure this is simple stuff but I just haven't been able to solve this.

Comment: You ought to check out `Document.getElementById()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById for getting the fields and their values and `EventTarget.addEventListener()`, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener for setting the button action.

Comment: Als there is no such thing as document.eval and if there was, your use is incorrect anyway

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an event listener to tell JavaScript 'hey, when this button is pressed, run this code'. With a button with id `action-button` you can add an event listener to it and get the values of your inputs when the button is clicked. You can then run your logic and show it.

```
document.getElementById("action-button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  const holdtime = document.getElementById("holdingtime").value;
});
```

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

Answer (score 0):

You need some eventListeners

Here I delegate from the form and use the change event of any of the fields. When all fields are filled in, I run the calculation

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() { // when page has loaded
  document.getElementById("calcForm").addEventListener("change", function() { // anything changed
    let holdtime = +document.getElementById("holdingtime").value; // use unary plus to convert to number
    let initialinvestment = +document.getElementById("initialinvestment").value;
    let monthlyreturn = +document.getElementById("monthlyreturn").value;

    let html = [];
    if (holdtime > 0 && initialinvestment > 0 && monthlyreturn > 0) {
      for (let i = 0; i <= holdtime; i++) {
        html.push(`<li>${initialinvestment.toFixed(0)}<hr></li>`);
        initialinvestment += initialinvestment * monthlyreturn;
      }
    }
    document.querySelector(".dprogramitself").innerHTML = html.join("");
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<form style="padding: 30px" id="calcForm">
  <input type="number" id="holdingtime" placeholder=" hold on time" />
  <input type="number" id="initialinvestment" placeholder="initial investment" />
  <input type="number" id="monthlyreturn" placeholder="monthly return" />
</form>


<ul class="dprogramitself" style="padding: 35px; padding-top: 1, font-size: 20px">
</ul>
```